# Why does padding an anchor tag create duplicate hyperlinks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
  nav ul li a
    {
        display : block ;
        text-align : center;
        font-weight : 600;
        text-decoration : none;
        color:#fff;
        background-color : rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
        margin : .2em 0;
        padding: .2em 0;
        border-radius: 1em;
        box-shadow : 1px 1px 4px #000;
    }
```

[image: Resultant Image]

removing the padding property makes everything fine but i want my anchors to be spacious but they look crushed that way please help

Comment: thank you andreas for editing the post

Comment: Can you post the HTML for this?

Comment: Yes, HTML please. That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use line-height instead of padding to add vertical space

Comment: thanks a lot for replying ... but that didnt work it still crushed my tags

Comment: My mistake, it seems like you have some other li>a with empty text inside, can you double check? Because if it is empty, then the padding will add height to it.

Answer (score 0):

Do your tags have anchor text inside them? If they don't have text, the text won't take up any space.. If you're planning to not have text in any of the links in the list, you'll likely want to set a `min-height` attribute on them to make sure they're at least a specific height.